# What is the meaning of "a holy kiss" in "Greet one another with a holy kiss". 1 Corinthians 16:20?

Tags: 1-corinthians

**1 Corinthians 16:20**

> "All the brothers send you greetings. Greet one another with **a holy kiss**". ESV. My emphasis.

Many years ago I was in a church congregation and the preacher was speaking about "a holy kiss". In the middle of the sermon he got us all to get up and walk around and greet other members of the congregation with a kiss. I don't recall that we were instructed whether those kisses should include men pecking men on the cheek, or women with women or men with women.

For me the preacher put all the emphasis on the word "kiss".  We were told that we should greet each other with a kiss. I don't criticise this preacher, maybe there was little affection demonstrated at this church at the time that this happened and he was dealing with that.

But is it possible that in this verse there is no encouragement to kiss? If the writer of 1 Corinthians was well aware that the Christians he was addressing often kissed each other, and he was aware that kissing is physical, then he would be aware that physical attraction
could interfere with the holiness of it.

Can we say if when Paul wrote 1 Corinthians he wanted to emphasise the word "holy" or the word "kiss"?

Is there something about "a holy kiss" as per 1 Cor 16:20 which is beyond cultural norms? Something which cannot be replaced by just a smile or a nod?

[ An example of something beyond cultural norms-"because of the angels", 1 Cor 11:10].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kissing as a simple non-sexual greeting, even between males, used to be more normal (see the story of Lord Nelson's death).

Two good Biblical examples can be found at the tail-end of Absalom's rebellion. "The king kissed Barzillai and blessed him, and [Barzillai] returned to his own home" (2 Samuel c19 v39. "And Joab said to Amasa 'Is it well with you my brother?' and Joab took Amasa by the beard with his right hand to kiss him" (2 Samuel ch20 v9). And Joab then stabbed him with the sword in his left hand.

So "holy" could simply mean "consciously doing it as a greeting between Christians on a Christian occasion, not one between non-Christians". Arguably, it would be appropriate in modern times to substitute the kind of greeting normally used in modern times. Handshake or hand-clasp? Air-kissing?

Comment: Pornos/male prostitute comes 4 times in 1 Cor. [esp' 5:11] Might Corinthian culture affect Paul's emphasis on "holy kiss"?